# Error in table(`202004.citibike.tripdata`) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a table and I keep getting the error attempt to make a table with 2^31 elements

### Frequency of gender

```
barplot(table(`202004.citibike.tripdata`), xlab="Gender",ylab="Frequency", main="Frequency Gender")
```

this is my line of code
https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html
my data set can be used from any of these csv files.
What do I do add to the line of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using the package `ggplot2` to make your bar chart, here's a solution using the first 10 entries from the "2014 - 01 Citi bike trip data" file.

Set up the test data:

```
df <- 
structure(list(tripduration = c(471, 1494, 464, 373, 660, 330, 
261, 337, 429, 1025), starttime = structure(c(1388534406, 1388534438, 
1388534639, 1388534715, 1388534718, 1388534755, 1388534764, 1388534801, 
1388534853, 1388534907), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), stoptime = structure(c(1388534877, 1388535932, 1388535103, 
1388535088, 1388535378, 1388535085, 1388535025, 1388535138, 1388535282, 
1388535932), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    `start station id` = c(2009, 536, 228, 519, 83, 422, 516, 
    380, 296, 540), `start station name` = c("Catherine St & Monroe St", 
    "1 Ave & E 30 St", "E 48 St & 3 Ave", "Pershing Square N", 
    "Atlantic Ave & Fort Greene Pl", "W 59 St & 10 Ave", "E 47 St & 1 Ave", 
    "W 4 St & 7 Ave S", "Division St & Bowery", "Lexington Ave & E 26 St"
    ), `start station latitude` = c(40.71117444, 40.74144387, 
    40.7546011026, 40.75188406, 40.68382604, 40.770513, 40.75206862, 
    40.73401143, 40.71413089, 40.74147286), `start station longitude` = c(-73.99682619, 
    -73.97536082, -73.971878855, -73.97770164, -73.97632328, 
    -73.988038, -73.96784384, -74.00293877, -73.9970468, -73.98320928
    ), `end station id` = c(263, 259, 2022, 526, 436, 526, 167, 
    435, 306, 447), `end station name` = c("Elizabeth St & Hester St", 
    "South St & Whitehall St", "E 59 St & Sutton Pl", "E 33 St & 5 Ave", 
    "Hancock St & Bedford Ave", "E 33 St & 5 Ave", "E 39 St & 3 Ave", 
    "W 21 St & 6 Ave", "Cliff St & Fulton St", "8 Ave & W 52 St"
    ), `end station latitude` = c(40.71729, 40.70122128, 40.75849116, 
    40.74765947, 40.68216564, 40.74765947, 40.7489006, 40.74173969, 
    40.70823502, 40.76370739), `end station longitude` = c(-73.996375, 
    -74.01234218, -73.95920622, -73.98490707, -73.95399026, -73.98490707, 
    -73.97604882, -73.99415556, -74.00530063, -73.9851615), bikeid = c(16379, 
    15611, 16613, 15938, 19830, 17343, 17880, 16275, 17318, 15525
    ), usertype = c("Subscriber", "Subscriber", "Subscriber", 
    "Subscriber", "Subscriber", "Subscriber", "Subscriber", "Subscriber", 
    "Subscriber", "Subscriber"), `birth year` = c("1986", "1963", 
    "1991", "1989", "1990", "1987", "1983", "1963", "1972", "1981"
    ), gender = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Load our packages and make a barplot of the rows counted by gender:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=gender))
```